# Possible to launch an application in the "Metro" environment and desktop environment? - Windows 8/8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, desktop-application

Ok, so I'm a major amature to the world of programing and I want to make an app that can be deployed through the Windows Store. This is mainly because it seems easier and cheaper than if I were to distribute it myself. I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 (hooray for free college software!) and I plan on using c# and JSON to pull some data from a public api.

My question is: If I develop an app so that it can be downloaded and installed from the Windows Store to be primarily be used in "Metro" mode, can I also add a button that makes it switch over to desktop mode like Google Chrome has?

Note: I have done some research on the subject and I think this is doable, but I could never find specifics on how it's done. I appreciate any insight you can provide!

Comment: Offtopic: are you sure it's legal to deploy an app to Windows Store on academic alliance licenced software?

Comment: @Tarec Hmm, that's a very interesting question. I actually don't have any idea, but I'm pretty sure anything I'll be doing in Visual Studio I could do in the express edition. The only thing I think I would need a paid version for is to attempt a Metro and desktop app in the same solution. I think I'm safe. Great question though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, as of Windows 8.1 there is no built-in support in WSA to run in a window on the desktop, unless you find that Snap mode suits your needs (it does for me). Primary browser is an exception, but it's not strictly just a WSA.

However, there are 3rd party solutions to do precisely that, e.g. [ModernMix](http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/), so technically it's possible, but goes outside of what you have access to during WSA development.

There are also talks about Windows 8.2 supporting this out of the box: [dailytech](http://www.dailytech.com/Report+Windows+82+Revives+Start+Menu+Runs+Metro+Apps+in+Desktop+Mode/article33896.htm)

Comment: That's a bummer. This seems like such an obvious thing that should have been in Windows 8.1. Oh well. :p